# Law of total probability problem

Tags: probability

The problem says

> A company employs $75\%$ of males and $25\%$ of females. The accounting department in this company provides jobs for $12\%$ of the males and $20\%$ of the females.
>
> - If an employee is chosen at random, what's the probability that he's from the accounting department?

Let $M$ be the event that the person is male, $F$ is the event that the person is female. Thus $P(M) = 0.75$, $P(F) = 0.25$. Let $A$ be the event that the person is from account dept.
$$P(A) = P(A|M)P(M) + P(A|F)P(F)$$

But I'm confused, is $12\%$ $P(A|M)$ or $P(M|A)$? Same for female part, and why?

Comment: Please see our [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: Apologizes, I'll use it when I ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are told that the accounting department provides jobs for **12% of the males**. In other words, **among the males**, $12\%$ are in the accounting department. In other other words, **given** that one is male, there is a $12\%$ chance he is employed by accounting:
$$P(A|M) = .12$$

To get a better understanding, trying drawing a picture. Or, imagine a company outing in which the employees wear their department tags. If the employees are separated into male and female, then $12\%$ of the males will be wearing accounting tags.

You are *not* told the chance that one is male **given** that they are in accounting, $P(M|A)$. You need to calculate this.

Similar reasoning follows for females.

Comment: I see, would it be also useful to try imagine who's the portion of who (between 2 things.) Like males can include (security, management, accounting..) each with its percent, but if it told 12% of account dept are males, then "males" is a portion of "account dept" like Account dept -> (males, females)? is that fine?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, you can imagine it the other way if that's what you're told. So, if they tell you "12% of the employees in accounting are male", then you know **given** that an employee is in accounting, there is a 12% chance that the employee is male, $P(M|A)$. This also tells you that there is an 88% chance that the employee is female, $P(F|A)$. If you are only told that, you would need to calculate $P(A|M)$ and/or $P(A|F)$ if necessary.